# Why are these WPF elements not being displayed completely?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I wrote a program in C#, which makes use of a user interface developed using WPF, with the markup in XAML.
However, when I start my application window-ed, [image]

this happens.

However, when I maximize the window,[image]

this happens.

It seems that my buttons are either not being drawn on the display canvas correctly (?) OR they are not being rendered correctly (?).

How should this issue be fixed? (The buttons must be displayed the way they have been shown in the latter image - even when the window is tiled.)

( The program was built using Visual Studio 2015 using DotNet 4.5.2)

Update : I forgot to add XAML code for the window - so here it is.

```
<Window x:Class="NKryptorTester_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NKryptorTester_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="NKryptor Desktop" Height="600" Width="1024">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonSignup" Click="ActionSignup" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Content="Signup" BorderThickness="0" Height="50" Width="250" FontSize="20" Margin="385,240,381,279" Background="#FF21877E"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonSignin" Click="ActionSignin" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Content="Signin" BorderThickness="0" Height="50" Width="250" FontSize="20" Margin="385,290,381,229" Background="#FF712687"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Add the Xaml for the window

Comment: XAML added. I forgot to add the XAML code earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rid of of fixed Margin and try something like that:

```
      <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <Button x:Name="ButtonSignup" Click="ActionSignup" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Content="Signup" BorderThickness="0" Height="50" Width="250" FontSize="20" Background="#FF21877E"/>
          <Button x:Name="ButtonSignin" Click="ActionSignin" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Content="Signin" BorderThickness="0" Height="50" Width="250" FontSize="20" Background="#FF712687"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: It almost worked. The first button renders correctly. I'm working on making the second button work fine as well.

Comment: Depending on your style you can have some fixed margin to set, maybe only on the second button.

Comment: Nice, i'm glad it helped.